# Want to build a bar chart using a list of Dictionary in angular 6

Tags: c#, angular6

I am new to angular and c#, I am trying to build a bar chart from list of Dictionary, that Dictionary I am getting from Query in c# to fetch values from DB. My Query looks like:

```
 public async Task<ListResultDto<DashboardCountDto>> CountAllTrainDocuments()
        {
                //var retList = new List<ListOfDocumentTypes>();
              var allTrainFiles = await _trainDocumentRepository.GetAllListAsync();
               var CountTrainFiles = allTrainFiles.GroupBy(t=> t.DocumentTypeName).
                                    Select(e => new DashboardCountDto{ 
                                         //Total = e.Count(),
                                    DocumentTypeName = e.Key,
             ProceesedDocumentCount = e.Count(g => g.Processed = true),
             UnProceesedDocumentCount = e.Count(g => g.Processed = false),
            
         }).ToList();
}
```

My DTO looks like:

```
public class DashboardCountDto : EntityDto<long>
    {
        //public int Total { get; set; }
        public string DocumentTypeName { get; set; }
        public int ProceesedDocumentCount { get; set; }
         public int UnProceesedDocumentCount { get; set; }

   }
```

Below code is used to connect C# and angular:

```
countAllTrainDocuments(): Observable<ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto> {
        let url_ = this.baseUrl + "/api/services/app/VariableLayoutDocument/CountAllTrainDocuments";
        url_ = url_.replace(/[?&]$/, "");

        let options_ : any = {
            observe: "response",
            responseType: "blob",
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                "Accept": "application/json"
            })
        };

        return this.http.request("post", url_, options_).pipe(_observableMergeMap((response_ : any) => {
            return this.processCountAllTrainDocuments(response_);
        })).pipe(_observableCatch((response_: any) => {
            if (response_ instanceof HttpResponseBase) {
                try {
                    return this.processCountAllTrainDocuments(<any>response_);
                } catch (e) {
                    return <Observable<ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto>><any>_observableThrow(e);
                }
            } else
                return <Observable<ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto>><any>_observableThrow(response_);
        }));
    }

    protected processCountAllTrainDocuments(response: HttpResponseBase): Observable<ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto> {
        const status = response.status;
        const responseBlob = 
            response instanceof HttpResponse ? response.body : 
            (<any>response).error instanceof Blob ? (<any>response).error : undefined;

        let _headers: any = {}; if (response.headers) { for (let key of response.headers.keys()) { _headers[key] = response.headers.get(key); }};
        if (status === 200) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            let result200: any = null;
            let resultData200 = _responseText === "" ? null : JSON.parse(_responseText, this.jsonParseReviver);
            result200 = ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto.fromJS(resultData200);
            return _observableOf(result200);
            }));
        } else if (status !== 200 && status !== 204) {
            return blobToText(responseBlob).pipe(_observableMergeMap(_responseText => {
            return throwException("An unexpected server error occurred.", status, _responseText, _headers);
            }));
        }
        return _observableOf<ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto>(<any>null);
    }
```

I have tried this code in angular 6

```
ngOnInit() {
        this._variableLayoutDocumentService.countAllTrainDocuments.subscribe((result: ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto) => {
          if (result) {
            for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
              this.barChartData[0].data.push(result[i].ProceesedDocumentCount);
              this.barChartData[1].data.push(result[i].UnProceesedDocumentCount);
              this.barChartLabels.push(result[i].DocumentTypeName);
            }
          }
        });;
      }

Its giving me 2 errors:
1. Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '() Observable<ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto>'.ts(2339)
2.any Property 'length' does not exist on type 'ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto'.ts(2339)
```

Please help in solving this issue, I want my chart should look like.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7env.png)

Comment: You might want to include the definitions for the type `ListResultDto` and `EntityDto`. `2.any Property 'length' does not exist on type 'ListResultDtoOfDashboardCountDto'.ts(2339)` -> I think it might expect an array here, however, you created your own wrapper type that might not have a length property.

Answer (score 0):

There is in-between information missing in your question.
C# is running server-side, whereas Angular is running in your browser.
Therefore Angular needs to make a request to a web server / api that provides this data.
To make this request using Angular, take a look at [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http):

What do you use to expose the C# objects to a http request?